# Owner/Group of files deployed via vsftpd user are always set to root:root

Tags: linux, vsftpd

I created a vsftpd user and added it to NetBeans and setup deployment with it.
But if I upload something then the owner is always changed to `root:root` which causes deployment problems. It should default to `nameOfTheFtpUser:www` instead of `root:root`. I often get "**Upload Files On Save failed for:**" because the file owner and group are changed to `root:root` ...

Update:
Maybe it is because I am working with Modman which uses symlinks.

How can I solve this?

**/etc/vsftpd.conf**

```
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
nopriv_user=ftpsecure
ftpd_banner=Willkommen auf dem Entwicklungsserver
ls_recurse_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
local_umask=022
chmod_enable=YES
file_open_mode=0777
anonymous_enable=NO
anon_world_readable_only=YES
syslog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ascii_upload_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
listen=YES
#listen_ipv6=YES

ssl_enable=NO
rsa_cert_file=
dsa_cert_file=
#
# Limit passive ports to this range to assis firewalling
pasv_min_port=30000
pasv_max_port=30100
```

Comment: Does [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/571289/vsftpd-default-uploaded-file-permissions-on-ubuntu-not-working) apply to the problem?

Comment: I think it is because I am using symlinks

Comment: See if the info in my link applies here. Symlinks normally do not affect permissions, they should be transparent.

Comment: @harrymc, I don't understand you, I already have these lines in my config file as you can see in my question.

Comment: See the accepted answer.